# how to grant additional permissions to %system.teamcity.auth.userId% account?

Tags: teamcity

TeamCity has %system.teamcity.auth.userId% account to perform special tasks, it is actually a variable that contains a username that changes for every run.

I need to grant this account additional permissions, how do I do this?  under what username this account resides?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to grant additional permissions to `system.teamcity.auth.userId` account.

`system.teamcity.auth.userId` represents a virtual entity, something like "buildUser". This buildUser has very limited set of permissions to let it get build-, buildConfiguration- and project-related data. You might refer to the [TeamCity issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-39206) for additional details.

To workaround this behavior you might explicitly specify the credentials for a real user via Configuration Parameters. `password display='hidden'` parameter spec hides it from "Run Custom Build" dialog (also password parameters are redacted from the build log).